# BULK INSERT error with unknown cause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, sql-server-2016

I am trying to BULK insert a rather wide (220 column) dataset into a SQL Server 2016 table using the following:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.[table] 
FROM 'C:\source.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'
);
```

From the start I had a couple of issues with the row terminator, but everything seemed to be working fine when I fixed it to be 'OX0A' instead of '\n' until I tried processing a rather large file (in relation to other I am loading). To give you an idea, it contains about 220 columns (destination being NVARCHAR(255), source is pretty much INT) and 10 000 rows. File file size is no larger than 40mb.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Some more info:

- I get the same error if I use FIRSTROW AND LASTROW.
- When trying to find the offending row, the file started working once I started removing rows (started working when I had about 1910 rows in my set).
- It it doesn't matter from where I remove the rows, If I keep the top 1910 rows or the bottom 1910 rows it works, but as soon as I add more rows (which are valid) it breaks again.
- I am about 99% sure there is nothing wrong with my row endings or other formatting issues.
- Errorfile is emptry even after the failure.

My gut feeling is that it has something to do with memory management, but as far as I know my memory is maxed out and the files themselves are rather small and should not be giving me memory issues.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to do a SAVE as on that file and see if the Encoding of the file is anything other than ANSI ? Me personally I have never had to use anything other than the standard '\n' ROWTERMINATOR .  The  '0x0A' sounds strange.

**Edit :**

Try these and see if any one of them succeeds:

1. SELECT A.* FROM 
   OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\source.txt', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS A
2. import using bcp and see if you get the same error
3. play with BATCH_SIZE , ROWS_PER_BATCH . Please go thru this link before you try as there are implications. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188267(v=sql.105).aspx
4. Try importing from the Export/Import Wizard ( Right Click on DB --> Tasks --> Import and go thru the screens ). See if this works.

To try inserting using OPENROWSET

insert into dbo.Table SELECT A.* FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\source.txt',     FORMATFILE='C:\source.Xml'
      ) as A

Now you need to generate the formatfile Source.xml using instructions from here --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx

bcp is a command line tool that ships with SQL Server. Unlike BULK Insert which runs from SSMS Query window this is a external tool. Plenty of help available on how to use it for formatfile generation (or otherwise)  on that link above. Goodluck I will check back later.

Comment: Just tried, same behavior, but what you mention did play a role in using 0x0A vs \n.

Comment: @tribe84 see my edit. Please try out and see if it helps narrowing down.

Comment: 1. Works, 2. Not familiar with bcp. 3. No dice, 4. Works.

Comment: @tribe84 If openrowset works then you can easily convert that into a insert stmt ... I will edit my post

Comment: I tried with bcp and it fails for me with the following error: SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file. Maybe it helps, but the file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ypk65UGS64Y25tSFdia2FISEk/view?usp=sharing. Here is the table https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ypk65UGS64cUJPVVNfSm52UWM/view?usp=sharing,

Comment: With openrowset I get a whole other can of worms :) I don't have headers for those files, rather, I determine which table it needs to go into at run-time. I had the issue of duplicate header rows when trying to use openrowset using Access Text Driver (Duplicate column names are not allowed in result sets obtained through OPENQUERY and OPENROWSET. The column name "0" is a duplicate.)

Comment: I get the same error except it is at line 228 and If I copy that line elsewhere it works fine lol. BAtchsize did not help too. I will take a look at this tomorrow (1am here )... very interesting problem.

Comment: Great the plot thickens lol ... I tried converting the columns to varchar from nvarchar but no luck ... will sleep over it ... ttyl ... thx

Comment: @tribe84  perhaps this might give you a clue .. I created my own sample csv files with 222 columns and 4000 rows (Using Excel) and it works like a charm. This leads me to believe that there is *some* issue with your sample file that only BULK INSERT does not like ... But I just cant find what it is . I checked to make sure that the number of comma's in your file are same for each row (221 Commas).

Comment: Thanks for the investigation mate. This is what I have done: I have just completed converting all the files to MS rather than Unix and will be using bcp to transfer over the files since that seems to be working. I will let you know what I find. I will leave this topic open for a couple of days to see if someone can definitively give an answer otherwise I will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: @tribe84 No worries, I 'am as eager as you to find out what trips BULK INSERT :) ... thanks for bringing up a great question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file in Notepad++.  that should show you what's going on.  I'm sure it's NOT what you think it is!!

Comment: I have opened it to view all the characters, the only weird thing I saw was that the row terminator was [LF] instead of [CR][LF]. This explains why ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A' worked. Other than that, I cannot figure it out, since it works for 1910 rows, but not for 1911 rows. It is really whacky behaviour and makes me doubt the BULK INSERT's stability. On a side note, I managed to use BCP and all worked well.